# Down memory lane: Please nominate the best answers of 2011?

Tags: discussion, answers, competitions

We've been running for over 6 years now, and I thought we should take the opportunity to look back at the best answers.

Please post an answer nominating your favourite / the best answer of 2011 (don't worry, we'll move onto more recent years soon).

You can nominate more than one answer, each in a separate post.

You can not nominate your own answers.

You must link to the answer.

This will run until we have 10 answers with at least one upvote, at which point the top three answers upvoted will receive bounties from myself (and anyone else who deems it worthwhile - hopefully you'll be generous with the bounties since you voted for them).

[This search may help you find answers from 2011](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer%20score%3a1%20created%3a2011).

Comment: Hey, that's not fair! Some of us only joined in 2015.

Comment: @JonathanReez *(don't worry, we'll move onto more recent years soon)* and that's worrying...

Comment: is it ok to vote on them whilst looking at/selecting them?

Comment: @GayotFow of course

Answer (score 10):

I nominate:

the [answer from October 28, 2011](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3083/101) by [Phelios](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/88/phelios), in response to :

[OK we're all adults here, so really, how on earth should I use a squat toilet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3080/101)

Comment: Of course you would nominate a toilet question. :P

Comment: @JoErNanO someone had to :)

Answer (score 6):

I nominate: Yousf's answer to [How to use sinks with separate hot/cold taps?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/how-to-use-sinks-with-separate-hot-cold-taps/3385) because I would have paid solid dobloons to know this trick back when I lived in the UK.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to specify an answer, and not only the question?

Comment: @mts the link points to an answer. The text unfortunately does not. Fixed.

Comment: the link still does not point to an answer for me, but the text refers to this one now: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3385/32134

Answer (score 1):

I nominate: hippietrail's answer about [Travelling between Japan and South Korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2984/9009). Brilliant answer full of first-hand experience.